# AdonisJS file upload issue. errno: -4037 code: "EXDEV"

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I am trying to upload image in AdonisJS but I always get the error:

> ```sh
> errno: -4037, code: "EXDEV", syscall: "rename", path:
> "C:\Users\User~1.ISH\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_79c1e16bf2495246d9ba136ac6f19135",
> dest: "D:\Projects\ppp\storage\WIN_20151011_17_45_53_Pro.jpg"
> ```

My code is:

```js
const imageFile = request.file('image', {
    maxSize: '10mb',
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg','JPG']
})

yield imageFile.move(Helpers.storagePath())

if (!imageFile.moved()) {
    return response.badRequest(imageFile.errors())
}
```

I googled and find that issue is with NodeJS because moving files from different directory then project is not allowed by default. But I also didn't find any configuration related to this in AdonisJS docs.

Comment: Github's issue: https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/438

Comment: @RomainLanz yes i had created this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/commit/1e36b4f44ce5dfebc39d46525f52dd2cae2e3439